# Arduino to Rasspberry Pi3 rosserial communication issue

Tags: arduino, rosserial, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hy @ all,

i’m having big troubles using rosserial and an Arduino UNO that publishes data with a baudrate of 57600.
The communication is very unstable and following all types of messages appear:

```
[INFO] [1492667619.104258]: Protocol version of client is unrecognized, expected Rev 1 (rosserial 0.5+)
[INFO] [1492667619.139384]: wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[INFO] [1492667621.822400]: wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[INFO] [1492667621.834504]: wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[INFO] [1492667624.639665]: wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[ERROR] [1492667638.922764]: Lost sync with device, restarting...
[INFO] [1492667638.949403]: Setup publisher on Acceleration [std_msgs/UInt16]
[INFO] [1492667641.931132]: wrong checksum for msg length, length 2
[INFO] [1492667641.938244]: chk is 125
[INFO] [1492667644.763389]: wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[INFO] [1492667647.562569]: wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[INFO] [1492667647.602618]: wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[INFO] [1492667650.391716]: wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[ERROR] [1492667664.819193]: Lost sync with device, restarting...
[INFO] [1492667664.842178]: Setup publisher on Acceleration [std_msgs/UInt16]
[INFO] [1492667667.752884]: wrong checksum for msg length, length 2
[INFO] [1492667667.755096]: chk is 125
[INFO] [1492667670.646117]: wrong checksum for msg length, length 2
[INFO] [1492667670.647877]: chk is 0
[INFO] [1492667670.652876]: wrong checksum for msg length, length 32253
[INFO] [1492667670.655812]: chk is 0
[INFO] [1492667673.536994]: wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[ERROR] [1492667673.540280]: Mismatched protocol version in packet: lost sync or rosserial_python is from different ros release than the rosserial client
[INFO] [1492667673.541983]: Protocol version of client is unrecognized, expected Rev 1 (rosserial 0.5+)
[INFO] [1492667673.586425]: wrong checksum for topic id and msg
[ERROR] [1492667691.379182]: Lost sync with device, restarting...
[INFO] [1492667691.403129]: Setup publisher on Acceleration [std_msgs/UInt16]
[INFO] [1492667694.464336]: wrong checksum for msg length, length 2
[INFO] [1492667694.466331]: chk is 0
[INFO] [1492667694.488039]: wrong checksum for msg length, length 32253
[INFO] [1492667694.490161]: chk is 0
[INFO] [1492667696.366441]: Send tx stop request
```

Do you have an idea how to fix this problem?

Thanks for your help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259687/arduino-to-rasspberry-pi3-rosserial-communication-issue/) by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2017-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Be sure that you have enough free memory on the Arduino side. I have abandoned trying to use rosserial_arduino on small-memory MCUs (2kb) because it was too unstable. The Arduino IDE will show you how much free memory you have after compiling. I found the system to be unstable with less than about 700 bytes free. rosserial uses quite a bit of static memory for buffers and message type names. You might try reducing the number of publishers and subscribers, or reduce the size of the input and output buffers. You can control all the sizes by using the internal `NodeHandle_` type instead of `NodeHandle`:

```
 ros::NodeHandle_<ArduinoHardware, 3, 2, 200, 150> nh;
```

Here, the node handle is set up to have up to 3 subscribers, up to 2 publishers, an input buffer size of 200, and an output buffer size of 150. (The defaults are 25, 25, 512, and 512, respectively, which uses up a lot of the RAM on a 2kb Arduino.)

If you're running out of memory, you might try `ros_arduino_bridge`. A different approach, less ROS-like on the Arduino side, but much less memory usage.

---

Originally posted by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) with karma: 1563 on 2017-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mtROS](https://answers.ros.org/users/29774/mtros/) on 2017-04-20**:
Thank you very much Mark for your answer! I switched in the meantime to sensor_msgs/imu in order to publish my data. Maybe I come back to your solution in a couple of days!